# Is there an archive of the Satellite Times magazine from the mid-late 90s?

Tags: artificial-satellite, reference-request

More of an misc. question. I am looking for the "Satellite Times" magazine which seems like it was in print in the mid-late 1990s.

Part of the articles published there could be found at [CELESTRAK](https://celestrak.org/columns/v01n01/) website (which also contains the cover photos of the magazine, if it's of any help), but I am curious to see the other articles written there as well.

Is there an archive somewhere online? Maybe PDFs? I have tried browsing the web but with no luck.

Comment: Somewhat replaced by the Monitoring Times, which then ceased publication in 2013. Perhaps replaced by https://www.thespectrummonitor.com/about-us.aspx (?). Oddly, given the ham radio community tendency to save everything, I could not readily find an archive on line. Note that "Satellite Times" also seems to be the name of another magazine (from the UK?) on satellite TV schedules (??) - did not look too closely from work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there an archive somewhere online? Maybe PDFs? I have tried browsing the web but with no luck.

https://worldradiohistory.com/Satellite-Times.htm